# How to group data by column and calculate the number of observations per group

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this DataFrame `df` with 3 columns: `id`, `type` and `activity`.

```
val myData = (Seq(("aa1", "GROUP_A", "10"),("aa1","GROUP_A", "12"),("aa2","GROUP_A", "hy"),("aa2", "GROUP_B", "14"),
              ("aa3","GROUP_B", "11"),("aa3","GROUP_B","12" ),("aa2", "GROUP_3", "12"))

val df = sc.parallelize(myData).toDF()
```

I need to group data by `type` and then calculate the number of activities for each `id`. This is the expected result:

```
type      id    count
GROUP_A   aa1   2
GROUP_A   aa2   1
GROUP_B   aa3   3
GROUP_B   aa2   1
```

This is what I tried:

```
df.groupBy("type","id").count().sort("count").show()
```

However it does not give a correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I minimally changed your sample data and it works for me:

```
//yours
val myData = (Seq(("aa1", "GROUP_A", "10"),("aa1","GROUP_A", "12"),("aa2","GROUP_A", "hy"),("aa2", "GROUP_B", "14"),("aa3","GROUP_B", "11"),("aa3","GROUP_B","12" ),("aa2", "GROUP_3", "12"))

//mine 
//removed the ( at the beginning
//changed GROUP_3 to GROUP_B
//other minor changes so that the resultant group by will look like you desired
val myData = Seq(("aa1", "GROUP_A", "10"),("aa1","GROUP_A", "12"),("aa2","GROUP_A", "12"),("aa3", "GROUP_B", "14"),("aa3","GROUP_B", "11"),("aa3","GROUP_B","12" ),("aa2", "GROUP_B", "12"))


//yours
val df = sc.parallelize(myData).toDF()
//mine
//added in column names

val df = sc.parallelize(myData).toDF("id","type","count")

df.groupBy("type","id").count.show
+-------+---+-----+
|   type| id|count|
+-------+---+-----+
|GROUP_A|aa1|    2|
|GROUP_A|aa2|    1|
|GROUP_B|aa2|    1|
|GROUP_B|aa3|    3|
+-------+---+-----+
```

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Thanks so much. It should be `toDF("id","type","count")` because `aa..` is `id`. Let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `column names` when you create `dataframe` and do the count on the `grouped data`. This should be easy

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val myData = Seq(("aa1", "GROUP_A", "10"),
  ("aa1","GROUP_A", "12"),
  ("aa2","GROUP_A", "hy"),
  ("aa2", "GROUP_B", "14"),
  ("aa3","GROUP_B", "11"),
  ("aa3","GROUP_B","12" ),
  ("aa3", "GROUP_B", "12"))

val df = sc.parallelize(myData).toDF("id", "type", "activity")
df.groupBy("type","id").count().sort("count").show()
```